# ActionBar Import not being recognized

Tags: android, api, import, android-actionbar

I am trying to use the BluetoothChat sample code as a base for an application I am working on. I don't understand why my android.app.ActionBar import isn't working. Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize it. My project build target is the Google API 2.3.1.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I don't know how specific I should be so if more info would help you answer my question, please ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android.app.ActionBar works only on 3.0 level 11 API

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the android blog available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at
>   the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's
>   Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default.
>   You may otherwise add the action bar by calling
>   requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom
>   theme with the windowActionBar property.